# Sending emails to multiple recipients

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send emails to N number of people. I have passed the email id of gmail to a value called toAddresses, since I need to separate those string elements with comma (,)

I used this technique

```
String[] contactList=request.getParameterValues("mail_contacts");

InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[contactList.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
    toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(contactList[i]+",");
    out.println("<p>"+toAddress[i]+"</p><p>"+toAddress[i].toString()+"</p>");
}
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
```

But I am getting an error from the console which says 
"Missing required header 'To'"

Kindly help me resolve this error

Comment: I don't believe that you need the comma when creating a new InternetAddress.

Comment: @Swati: java.io.IOException: No content
 javax.mail.internet.MimePartDataSource.getInputStream(MimePartDataSource.java:108)
 javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
 javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1383)
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1743)
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1719)
 com.mpigeon.SendMails.doPost(SendMails.java:167)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)I am getting this exceptions in the console

Comment: What's in `com.mpigeon.SendMails`?

Comment: Remove the trailing comma. The exception you have just posted has nothing to to with the to-addresses.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but in your code toAddress is an array of InetAdresses and
when you are setting the contact list you are putting:

```
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
```

I believe toAddress Should be toAddress[position of array] I'm not entirely sure try doing:

```
String[] contactList=request.getParameterValues("mail_contacts");

InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[contactList.length]; 
for (int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++) {
    toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(contactList[i]+",");
    out.println("<p>"+toAddress[i]+"</p><p>"+toAddress[i].toString()+"</p>");
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
}
```